# Синтаксический разбор предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Даль приводит в своем словаре поговорку :
*Много снегу - много хлеба.*
Что у нас в данном случае с грамматической основой? Есть ли варианты ответа, и какой из них наиболее признанный и авторитетный.

Comment: Вообще говоря, я не считаю, что грамматическую основу здесь правильно обозначили ка гибрид подлежащего и сказуемого. В нашем языке много разнообразных односоставных предложений, и задача грамматики - определить их структуру, как бы составить реестр наших грамматических возможностей. Среди односоставных предложений  есть стандартные, а есть не часто встречающиеся или неоднозначно определяемые - именно с ними интересно работать на форуме ЛИНГВИСТОВ.

Comment: Большинство односоставных предложений являются сказуемостными, назывные предложения - очень небольшая их часть. При определении вида предложения НЕ СТОИТ ИЗМЕНЯТЬ ЕГО СТРУКТУРУ: подставлять или переставлять слов а – иначе это будет уже другое предложение. Например: (1) Снег, много снега!  До самого горизонта – бесконечное белое поле.  (2) Снега много, и мы проваливаемся по пояс.  Неужели нет разницы между «много снега» и «снега много»? Может ли  назывное предложение может входить в сложное?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Количественные числительные, а также слова с количественным значением являются неделимым словосочетанием. Поэтому "много снега" - это единый член предложения (как и "много хлеба"). Что касается характеристики предложения, то это бессоюзное сложное предложение, первая часть обозначает условие того, о чем говорится во второй, поэтому ставится тире.

Comment: Если мы добавим глагол (*много снега выпало*), то как в этом случае будем рассуждать? Подлежащее - *много снега*. Почему же в поговорке это не подлежащее, не очень понятно.

Comment: Можете назвать это подлежащими, почему нет? Снег. Много снега. Много снега- много хлеба.  Вопрос терминологии. Я предпочитаю в односоставном предложении избегать термина подлежащее - сказуемое, так как это взаимосвязанные сущности, нет подлежащего - нет и сказуемого. Просто - главный член односоставного предложения.

Comment: Все-то у Вас просто)  
*Снега у нас нынче много! Хлеба будет еще больше!*

Comment: Однажды я здесь задавал вопрос о сказумом в предложении "У меня нет денег". Очень многие форумчане убеждали меня, что сказуемое - "нет", а не "нет денег". Чем же отличается "нет денег" от "много денег" (много снегу)?

Comment: *Этой зимой мало снега*.  
Получается, что главный член односоставного предложения, выраженный такого рода словосочетанием, соединяет в себе признаки и подлежащего, и сказуемого. Но нельзя забывать, что при этом обычно опускается глагол/ глагол-связка.

Comment: А эллиптических предложений в грамматике больше нет?   (Эллиптическими называются предложения особого построения, состоящие из подлежащего и дополнения или обстоятельства,сказуемое в таких предложениях всегда отсутствует). Например: "Посреди небесных тел лик луны туманный".

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что здесь две грамматических основы, представленных сказуемыми "много" и "много" (безличные предложения, входящие в состав бессоюзного сложного)

Comment: Где же здесь СПП? Где Вы видите подчинительный союз?

Comment: Извините, в спешке проскочило СПП. Я исправился.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь возможны два варианта.

Вариант 1. Простое предложение: предмет и его признак с пропущенной связкой, причем предмет и признак связаны отношениями обусловленности.

Похожие примеры:Долголетие - это физкультура. Хорошо вспаханное поле - это урожай.

Подлежащее (предмет) и сказуемое (признак) выражены количественно-именными сочетаниями.

Вариант 2. Бессоюзное сложное предложение (первое предложение - это условие второго). Тогда "много" - это сказуемое в безличном предложении.